# How to send SSRS reports from two different "from" addresses?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have same report that I would like to send to two different clients from two different e-mail addresses.

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a way to do this from an SSRS e-mail subscription.

You should be able to do this without too much extra effort by creating a File Share subscription to drop off the file and then run sp_send_dbmail to send the e-mail with the file from the File Share subscription attached. sp_send_dbmail allows you to specify the FROM address so each client could be sent from a different e-mail address.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Create subscriptions to generate the files.

Create a stored procedure to send the files.

Create a job in SSMS to run your stored procedure after the file is generated.

Revel in your success.